# 目 as "eye" or ordinal marker

Tags: translation, words

In *Sakurasou no Pet na Kanojo*'s opening, there is this part:

> 1回めまぐれで
>
> 2回めってどうだろう
>
> 偶然じゃないよね？3回目が合うのは

I understand it, but one part: the translations I found say "The third time our eyes meet", and I noticed that at least in some written version "1回め" and "2回め" use め, while "3回目" uses 目.

I tried to understand if the 目 in 3回目 is ordinal ("The third time") or "eye" ("The third [time our] eyes"), but I didn't really find anything useful: if it's ordinal, I can't understand the subject of 合う: is it left unsaid, like "The third time [our eyes] met"?

If it's "eye", I'm not sure why 1回め and 2回め has an ordinal marker, while 3回目 doesn't, since they all mean "The nth time".

I'm wondering if it's meant to be a word play, like using 目 as ordinal, but impliying "eyes" since it means that too; no luck in finding info about that, though.

Edit: Without ordinal marker it should be cardinal, but I'm not sure if, maybe as poetic license it being in a song, it could be left out while still having an ordinal meaning.

Comment: If no ordinal suffix, it'll be a cardinal number, right?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure if, maybe as poetic license it being in a song, it could be left out; thanks for pointing it out, I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lyrics are arguably wordplay-like, in that they try to invite listeners into a [garden path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence). But the only way eventually parses meaningfully is 3回 "three times" + 目が合う "eyes meet". This 目 cannot be a suffix and a noun at the same time.

By the way, lyrics I found in Japanese sites all seem to have spaces in between, which suggest the official way of parsing.

> 1回め まぐれで
> 2回め ってどうだろう
> 偶然じゃあないよね? 3回 目が合うのは